# Changing the size of a Chart Legend

Tags: charts, legending

I'm trying to get a reasonable match for the following PieChart.

[image]

I understand how to make the piechart,  tweak the colors, placement of labels, etc.

```
PieChart[{17, 6, 9, 6, 4, 29, 29}, 
 ChartLegends -> {"Job", "Homework", "Meals", "Relaxation", "Travel", 
   "Sleep", "School"}, 
 ChartStyle -> {Blue, Red, Purple, Pink, Green, Yellow, Orange}, 
 LegendAppearance -> "Column"]
```

The default size of the legend seems really small, with such a small "swatch" it's hard to match the colors.  The only command (that I can find) to adjust the Legend is with `LegendAppearance`,  and this appears to only change to rows or columns.  Is it possible to increase the size of the legend relative to the entire plot?

Answer (score 2):

By using `SwatchLegend[]` legends can be customised. In the current case `LegendMarkerSize` can be adjusted to get bigger markers.

```
PieChart[{17, 6, 9, 6, 4, 29, 29}, 
 ChartLegends -> 
  SwatchLegend[{"Job", "Homework", "Meals", "Relaxation", "Travel", 
    "Sleep", "School"}, LegendMarkerSize -> 40], 
 ChartStyle -> {Blue, Red, Purple, Pink, Green, Yellow, Orange}, 
 LegendAppearance -> "Column"]
```

[image]

Comment: Didn't know that function, perfect,  I am regularly in debt to this community for their amazing (and quick!) help!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use legend options as sub-options for `LegendAppearance`

```
PieChart[{17, 6, 9, 6, 4, 29, 29}, 
 ChartLegends -> {"Job", "Homework", "Meals", "Relaxation", "Travel", 
     "Sleep", "School"}, 
 ChartStyle -> {Blue, Red, Purple, Pink, Green, Yellow, Orange}, 
 LegendAppearance -> {LegendMarkerSize -> 30}]
```

[image]

Use

```
LegendAppearance -> {LegendMarkerSize -> 30, 
  LegendLayout -> {"Column", 2}, 
  LegendMarkers -> "Bubble",
  "MarkerLayout" -> "After"}
```

to get

[image]